# Java assignment, input selection

Tags: java, selection, user-input

I need help with my code: I'm brand new to Java

How do I get the string "user" variable to display my choice after I've entered the choice?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;                 
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        String me = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input name!");
        System.out.println("Your name is: " + me);
        String user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your choice!");
        System.out.println("Your choice is: " + user);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your choice is: " + user);

            if(user.equals('1'))

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username" + me + user);
    }  
}
```

Comment: you're pretty close already. look in JOptionPane class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes when comparing strings

```
 if(user.equals("1"))  // double quotes

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username" + me + user);
```

Comment: That hasn't worked. It still wont display the message I want when I type 1 into the input box :/

Comment: It works for me. I used you exact code, replacing the single quotes with double quotes. It pops up a message "usernamepaul1" `"Username" + me + user`. That's how you have it. You should add spaces for the message to be more clear `"Username " + me + " " + user`

Comment: You need to press ok again after the user message displays, to see the next message

Comment: I typed in `Paul` for the first dialog, the `1` for the second dialog. Then a dialog pops up showing 1, I press Ok, then another dialog pops up showing '"usernamepaul1"`. Works.

Comment: If you don't want the user number message dilaog to pop up, just delete this line `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your choice is: " + user);`, that the dialog popped up will show `'"usernamepaul1"`

Comment: Thanks! I never seen that. God damn syntax! haha thanks guys!